# Uploading multiple files in one folder with one form submission

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I've created a custom Google Form which allows a logged in Google user to include  multiple files with the form.
The files are uploaded into a newly created folder in Google Drive.
The Google Script uses the current user's email address + current date and time as the folder name.

## Problem and expected result:

Because of the `forEach` function, the script uploads each file into a separate folder (with the same name).
I would like to upload each file of **one** form submission into **one** folder.

## HTML:

```
<iframe name="hidden_iframe" id="hidden_iframe" style="display:none;" onload="if(submitted)  { picUploadJs(myForm); }"></iframe>
<form id="myForm" class="col s12" action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/xxx/formResponse" target="hidden_iframe"  onsubmit="submitted=true;">
  <input placeholder="1234" name="entry.1234" id="user" type="text">
  <label for="user">User:</label>
  <input name="picToLoad" type="file" id="sampleFile" />
  <div id="status" style="display: none">
  Uploading. Please wait...
  </div>
  <button type="submit" name="action">Send</button> <!-- Modified -->
</form>
```

## Javascript:

```
 function picUploadJs(myForm) {
    const f = document.getElementById("files");
    [...f.files].forEach((file, i) => {
    const fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = (e) => {
      const data = e.target.result.split(",");
      const obj = {fileName: file.name, mimeType: data[0].match(/:(\w.+);/)[1], data: data[1]};
      document.getElementById('status').style.display = 'inline';
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateOutput).processForm(obj);
    }
    fr.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
  }

  function updateOutput() {
    var outputDiv = document.getElementById('status');
    outputDiv.innerHTML = "The File was UPLOADED!";
    window.location='https://Thankyou';
  }
```

## Google Script:

```
function doGet(e) {
  Logger.log("doGet done");
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('test')
    .evaluate() // evaluate MUST come before setting the Sandbox mode
    .setTitle('Form')
    //.setSandboxMode();//Defaults to IFRAME which is now the only mode available
}

function processForm(theForm) {
  var dateTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+2", "dd-MM-yy_HH-mm");
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var parentFolder=DriveApp.getFolderById('xxxxx');  
  var newFolder=parentFolder.createFolder(email + "_" + dateTime);
  var newFolderId = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(newFolder).next().getId();

  var fileBlob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(theForm.data), theForm.mimeType, theForm.fileName);
  var fldrSssn = DriveApp.getFolderById(newFolderId);
  fldrSssn.createFile(fileBlob);
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When the files are submitted, you want to create one new folder every submitting.
- You want to upload multiple files to the created folder.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

### Modified scripts:

#### HTML:

Please modify as follows.

From:

```
<input name="picToLoad" type="file" id="sampleFile" />
```

To:

```
<input name="picToLoad" type="file" id="files" multiple />
```

#### Javascript:

Please modify `picUploadJs()`.

```
function picUploadJs(myForm) {
  const f = document.getElementById("files");
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((folderId) => { // Added
    var files = [...f.files];
    files.forEach((file, i) => {
      const fr = new FileReader();
      fr.onload = (e) => {
        const data = e.target.result.split(",");
        const obj = {fileName: file.name, mimeType: data[0].match(/:(\w.+);/)[1], data: data[1]};
        document.getElementById('status').style.display = 'inline';
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(() => {
          if (i == files.length - 1) updateOutput();
        }).processForm(obj, folderId); // Modified
      }
      fr.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
  }).createFolder();
}
```

#### Google Apps Script:

I separated `processForm()` to `processForm()` and `createFolder()`.

```
// Added
function createFolder() {
  var dateTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+2", "dd-MM-yy_HH-mm");
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('xxxxx');
  var newFolder = parentFolder.createFolder(email + "_" + dateTime);
  var newFolderId = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(newFolder).next().getId();
  return newFolderId;
}

// Modified
function processForm(theForm, newFolderId) {
  var fileBlob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(theForm.data), theForm.mimeType, theForm.fileName);
  var fldrSssn = DriveApp.getFolderById(newFolderId);
  fldrSssn.createFile(fileBlob);
  return true;
}
```

### Note:

- In your HTML, the top line is as follows.

  ```
  <form id="myForm" target="hidden_iframe" onsubmit="submitted=true;">
  ```

  From [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55575819), if you are using the following lines, please update your question. I supposed that you are using the following script.

  ```
  <iframe name="hidden_iframe" id="hidden_iframe" style="display:none;" onload="if(submitted)  { picUploadJs(myForm); }"></iframe>
  <form id="myForm" action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/xxx/formResponse" target="hidden_iframe" onsubmit="submitted=true;">
  ```

If this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Perfect! That's it, thank you.
I've added the missing lines in the HTML part.

Comment: @Bldjef Thank you for replying and updating it. I'm glad your issue was resolved.